# Scrapy Conditonal HTML values

Tags: python, scrapy

Code below locates most the elements I am looking for. However the The temperature and windspeed have tags that vary depending on weather severity. How can get the code below to consistent get the right TempProb and windspeeds values on the page.

```
import scrapy

class NflweatherdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'NFLWeatherData'
allowed_domains = ['nflweather.com']
start_urls = ['http://nflweather.com/']

def parse(self, response):
    # pass
    # Extracting the content using css selectors
    Datetimes = response.xpath(
        '//div[@class="fw-bold text-wrap"]/text()').extract()
    awayTeams = response.xpath('//span[@class="fw-bold"]/text()').extract()
    homeTeams = response.xpath(
        '//span[@class="fw-bold ms-1"]/text()').extract()
    TempProbs = response.xpath(
        '//div[@class="mx-2"]/span/text()').extract()
    windspeeds = response.xpath(
        '//div[@class="text-break col-md-4 mb-1 px-1 flex-centered"]/span/text()').extract()
    # winddirection =

    # Give the extracted content row wise
    for item in zip(Datetimes, awayTeams, homeTeams, TempProbs, windspeeds):
        # create a dictionary to store the scraped info
        scraped_info = {
            'Datetime': item[0],
            'awayTeam': item[1],
            'homeTeam': item[2],
            'TempProb': item[3],
            'windspeeds': item[4]
        }

        # yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
        yield scraped_info
```